# Copy data between two DBs with different DB users

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have three environments (or Databases) have been set up in one SQL server. And three different logins / users are mapped to each of those. Eg:

Env (DB) 1 - DBUser 1
Env (DB) 2 - DBUser 2
Env (DB) 3 - DBUser 3

Apparently DBUser1 doesn't have permissions to access any ENVs other than his one.

I have a requirement where I need to copy some data from ENV1 to say ENV3 from the code (C#). But it doesn't allow me to do so as my main environment is ENV1 (where my web site is connecting to by default) and ENV3 cannot be accessed by DBUSer1.

As soon as I have given permission to DBUser1 to access ENV3, it works. But then I loss the whole purpose of having different users. Are there any other alternatives?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and 3.5 .Net framework

Comment: Can you not connect to DB1 ans DBUser1 and DB3 as DBUser3?

Comment: I can, but not within one statement. And also I need to store the data that I have got from DB1 somewhere so that I can re-access it after connecting to DB3. I can probably use the cache but the volume of data could be large sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

User permissions in SQL server are highly granular.

I would suggest a stored procedure in ENV1 with privaliges to ENV3 that is available to ENV1 users. This keeps your permission structure secure and the code accessable to ENV1 users does not need to contain (or even know about) any credentials for ENV2 or ENV3.

Comment: How can you create a stored proc in ENV1 with "privileges to ENV3 " ? The user of ENV3 doesn't show up in ENV1.

Comment: The procedure is located in the database where the data access happens (ENV3) which has to be configured to allow remote procedure calls from ENV1. The details depend on your individual configuration (google Remote Procedure Calls SQL Server). You call by EXEC [ServerName].[DataBaseName].[user].[Procedure name]. You would normally put this in another stored procedure in ENV1 which may do some pre and post processing. You need to grant appropriate permissions so that a user on ENV1 can access ENV3 but that user will not be able to access ENV3 directly.

Answer (score 0):

[SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) is the way to go it seems. Thanks everyone.